# jasper report studio - how to add line in detail band. A page which has blank detail-band is following

Tags: jasper-reports

I am junior web developer in Korea.
I know that you may not understand well what I want to talk about.
Please tell me If I wrote wrong.

I recently use jasper studio for making report like this.

[image: 1]

I add border-left and border-right in subreport.
But result is different from what I wanted to do.

Of course I added border-left and border-right in Detail band directly, it made different result as well.
Although this way looks fine, whenever I click preview tab, a page that has blank detail band is following page which is okay.

anybody help me, please :)

Comment: That's how jasper works.. maybe you should try to use the background band draw your borders on this.

Comment: Sorry for late, Petter. Thank you